# TypeError: _request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cookies' (aiohttp)

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

```
import random
import asyncio
import json
import aiohttp
import sys
import urllib
from lxml.html.soupparser import parse
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from threading import Thread

def ttest():
    async def fetch(url, session):
        headers = {
            'Host': 'example.com'
        }
        cookies2 = {
            'test': 'test'
        }

        data = '{"test":"test"}'
        async with session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, cookies=cookies2) as response:
            return await response.read()
    async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
        async with sem:
            html = await fetch(url, session)
            print(html)


    async def run(r):
        url = "https://test.com"
        tasks = []
        sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            for i in range(r):
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, url, session))
                tasks.append(task)
            responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            await responses

    number = 1
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(number))
    loop.run_until_complete(future)

ttest()
```

This is the error: `TypeError: _request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cookies'`

I want use cookies like you see in the code, but i can not, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature was added on aiohttp GitHub master but not released yet.

Please either install aiohttp from GitHub or wait for a while for aiohttp 3.5 release.

I hope to publish it in a few days.